# How does Apache HttpClient's support of cookies work?

Tags: cookies, httpclient

Does Apache HttpClient support cookies coded in javascript in a site's html or just those sent by the server through http?

edit:

If not, how would you go about finding the javascript cookies, using wireshark or another sniffer?

Comment: What programming-language/platform are you talking about? "HttpClient" is a pretty common name for HTTP client libraries.

Comment: That said, it's pretty unlikely than an HTTP client library is going to support cookies set via JavaScript, as doing so would require executing the JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, HttpClient is a... client... library. The thing that receives cookies is a server. Not the same thing.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses, next edit, how would you find the javascript cookies, using a sniffer, and would wireshark find them all? - at the moment, even doing something as basic as signing into yahoo mail, with wireshark running, using a web browser, does not identify all set-cookie headers.

Comment: Yahoo login uses https. How are you dealing with that?

Comment: I wasn't aware that https is really much different than http when it comes to response headers, so I'm not really sure. What should I do to see set-cookie headers of an https response?

Comment: @SamAdams I mentioned https because you mentioned using a sniffer. HTTPS is HTTP over SSL - the cookies work the same way (for the most part - HTTPS also gets cookies tagged as "secure"). The issue is that everything including the headers will be encrypted, so unless your sniffer is set up to decrypt you'll be missing all of the HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really give a lot of context, so it's hard to tell what sort of solution is appropriate to your problem.

If I wanted to find the JavaScript cookies sent by a site I'd probably do it from within a browser. As I mentioned in my comments above, reading the cookies set by JavaScript on the client side (in the general case) requires executing the JavaScript. Doing this "correctly" requires then entire environment that's visible to JavaScript, which is a pretty large fraction of a browser.

If a human operator is ok (eg: if this is for debugging), then you could use something like Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to examine the cookies. If you need something more automated, one option might be to write a browser extension.

There are other options that involve more work and/or less precision, but without knowing more about the constraints of your problem it's impossible to know which of those other options would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I want to write a java program which logs onto an https server, posts a couple requests, establishes state with user Id and password, makes a few "clicks" around the site, and automates the process with different info which is to be posted each time through, but the whole time, I need the site to continue establishing the session with the first user Id. At this stage I don't see how to automatically read in JavaScript cookies which the server expects my http headers to make further requests with, but obviously, http headers are easier to read in with java.net .

Comment: Comment got cut off. ... As responses from a server, or set cookie headers.